# How to upload images easliy in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to an imageGallery.How to upload images easliy in Meteor.I am using Mongo.
Can you please suggest a method.A Document has four images.

Answer (score 1):

Just Google for "meteor image upload" and look for how people are doing it already.

Recommendations were the [meteor-uploads package](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) and [filepicker.io](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Filepicker.io-Uploads-and-Image-Conversion-hIpSwJQV3HJ).